# get_post_custom: get image URL instead of image ID

Tags: images, post-meta, urls

I know the value of a image custom field will give me the attachemnt ID. In a loop over all custom fields, how can I found out if the field is an image? And then get the image URL of the attachemnt?

My code:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => array( 'my_type'), 
               'posts_per_page' => 1000, 
               'fields' => 'all' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

// Custom fields being attached
$retArray = array();
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post->ID);  

    // Some code to get the actual image url from fields that are images:
    // MISSING!

    // Combine $post and custom field array to new array
    array_push($retArray, array('post' => $post, 'fields' => $custom_fields));
endwhile;
```

Answer (score -1):

If its your own custom post type you should know the field names? Iterate through the fields - or better just get the required field - an then use the attachment Id with wp_get_attachment_image_src.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Chech the codex for further examples and Google for "WordPress custom post type fields".

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem.

Comment: Thanks rockaut, yes I do know the names of the fields. Would have loved to have them "translated" by default though. I think I can live with this though....